# Enlarge "persisitent" image on USB stick after installation?

Tags: installation, usb, persistence

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a USB pendrive using an installer provided by my my employer (the idea is to use Ubuntu instead of the preinstalled OS to use the business notebook also for private purposes). This installer seems similar to the Pendrive install and uses a persistent image on the USB stick to save data. This image is mounted at /cow. So far the system runs fine.

I used (only) 1GB for the persistent image. I would like to enlarge it without reinstalling the Ubuntu system. How do I do this? I have access to a second computer (Macbook) and I can use the shell, but I'm a little unsure as how to proceed.

Any ideas welcome!

Answer (score 0):

If you boot from a Live CD you can mount and access the casper-rw file on the Persistent USB using:

```
sudo mkdir /media/casper

sudo mount -o loop casper-rw /media/casper/
```

You can then move the contents of the casper-rw file to an ext2 partition named casper-rw, (on the persistent drive), then delete the casper-rw file.

I have not tried this exact method so better to keep a copy of the original casper-rw file as backup.